# A closed form for a triple integral involving Heron's formula

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, elliptic-integrals

Let
$$S(x,y,z)=\frac14\sqrt{(x+y+z) (-x+y+z) (x-y+z) (x+y-z) }\tag1$$
(note that it's Heron's formula for the area of a triangle with sides of lengths $x,y,z$).

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral in a closed form:
$$\mathcal U=\int_0^1\int_0^x\int_{x - y}^{x + y}\sqrt{S(x,y,z) } dz dy dx.\tag2$$
I wasn't able to evaluate it symbolically (either manually or using *Mathematica*), but using numerical integration and heuristic methods, I found a plausible form:
$$\mathcal U\stackrel{\color{gray}?}=\frac\pi{12\sqrt{2 }}+\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^4\sqrt{10 }}{1440 \pi^2}\left(\left(\small\frac12-\frac1{\sqrt{5 \phi }}\right)\textbf K(\alpha)^2-\textbf K(\alpha) \textbf E(\alpha)\right)\\ \quad\quad\;\approx0.117599420842157114228246644831065494814051852697…,\tag3$$
where $\textbf K(\cdot),\textbf E(\cdot)$ are the complete elliptic integrals of [the first](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) and [the second](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html) kind, and $\alpha=\frac1{\phi \sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt{2 \phi}}$.

Can we prove that $(3)$ is indeed the true value of the integral?

---

*Update:* You might ask, what heuristic methods could possibly give us the conjectured value? Here is a brief explanation.

First, calculate a sequence of values of $\int\!\int\!\int S^{2n}dz dy dx,n\in\mathbb N;$ their evaluation is straightforward and they are all rational numbers. Then, use [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to find a possible recurrence relation for that sequence. We need at least $30$ elements of the sequence to get a result:
$$\small{(5+2 n)^2 (7+4 n) (9+4 n) (11+4 n) (27+20 n)\cdot a(n+2)=\\4 (2+n) (7+4 n) \left(6750+16947 n+15764 n^2+6416 n^3+960
   n^4\right)\cdot a(n+1)+\\128 (1+n)^2 (2+n) (3+2 n) (3+4 n) (47+20 n)\cdot a(n)}\tag4$$
Of course, there is no guarantee that this relation holds for all larger $n$, but we cross our fingers  and conjecture that it does. Next, use [`FunctionExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html) to find a possible explicit expression for the general term determined by this recurrence relation; it's complicated and involves generalized hypergeometric functions; we also need to manually adjust a periodic factor to ensure the result remains real even for non-integer $n$. After some simplifications we arrive at this:
$$\small\tfrac{4^n (20 n+27) \Gamma (2 n+2)\sqrt\pi}{(n+1) (16 n+12) \Gamma \left(2 n+\frac{7}{2}\right)}\,{_5F_4}\left(1,n+\tfrac{3}{2},n+\tfrac{3}{2},n+\tfrac{3}{2},n+\tfrac{47}{20};n+\tfrac{27}{20},n+\tfrac{7}{4},n+2,n+\tfrac{9}{4};-4\right)\tag5$$
Then we cross our fingers again  and conjecture that the same formula holds for all non-integer $n$ as well. Next, substitute $n=1/4$ and use `FunctionExpand` again to expand the generalized hypergeometric functions in terms of elliptic integrals. The result is quite large and unwieldy ($19$ terms), but it appears to match the integral numerically, which is a sign we might be on the right track. We cross our fingers one more time  and conjecture that only a few terms of the expression are actually linearly independent over $\mathbb Z,$ and the result can be significantly simplified. Using [`FindIntegerNullVector`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIntegerNullVector.html) and high enough numeric precision, we find a possible basis, and a linear combination of its elements that numerically matches the integral. After some radical denestings (using [`ResourceFunction["RadicalDenest"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RadicalDenest/)) and other simplifications, this gives us the conjectured value $(3).$

Comment: Why do you care about $\mathcal{U}$?

Comment: @FShrike Don't you find it an inherently beautiful and immediately appealing question that you wish you have thought about a long time ago? I do. 

Comment: This is a beautiful problem and the path to solution more than interesting

Comment: Are you sure ? `N[Pi/(12*Sqrt[2]) + 
  Gamma[1/4]^4*Sqrt[10]/(
   1440 *Pi^2)*((1/2 - 1/Sqrt[5*GoldenRatio])*
      EllipticK[1/(GoldenRatio Sqrt[2]) + 1/Sqrt[2 GoldenRatio]]^2 - 
     EllipticK[1/(GoldenRatio Sqrt[2]) + 1/Sqrt[2 GoldenRatio]]*
      EllipticE[1/(GoldenRatio Sqrt[2]) + 1/Sqrt[2 GoldenRatio]])]`  gives :`0.119996` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk There is a definition quirk in _Mathematica_: what is usually denoted by $\textbf K(k)$ corresponds to `EllipticK[k^2]` in _Mathematica_. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html#:~:text=It%20is%20implemented%20in%20the%20Wolfram%20Language%20as%20EllipticK%5Bm%5D

Comment: Ok works fine. Thanks

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Well, I was initially wondering why you chose the bounds you chose, but now I realise these are basically the maximal bounds you can have to keep the integrand real valued

Comment: Your $\alpha$ is essentially a singular value with $\alpha=k(e^{-\pi/\sqrt {5}})$. The calculation of $K, E$ for this value of $k$ should match the answer given by David H.

Comment: Seems that you have found a modular equation without intend it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

---

Define the function $S:\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\mid0\le y\le x\land x-y\le z\le x+y\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ bye the expression

$$S{\left(x,y,z\right)}:=\frac14\sqrt{(x+y+z)(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z)},$$

and let $\mathcal{U}$ denote the value of the triple integral

$$\mathcal{U}=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\int_{x-y}^{x+y}\mathrm{d}z\,\sqrt{S{\left(x,y,z\right)}}\approx0.117599.$$

---

Observe that $S$ has the following scaling property:

$$\begin{align}
S{\left(x,xt,xu\right)}
&=\frac14\sqrt{(x+xt+xu)(-x+xt+xu)(x-xt+xu)(x+xt-xu)}\\
&=\frac14\sqrt{x^{4}(1+t+u)(-1+t+u)(1-t+u)(1+t-u)}\\
&=x^{2}\cdot\frac14\sqrt{(1+t+u)(-1+t+u)(1-t+u)(1+t-u)}\\
&=x^{2}S{\left(1,t,u\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

We can use this property to trivialize one of the integrations of $\mathcal{U}$ and reduce it to a double integral:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{U}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\int_{x-y}^{x+y}\mathrm{d}z\,\sqrt{S{\left(x,y,z\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,x\int_{1-t}^{1+t}\mathrm{d}u\,x\sqrt{S{\left(x,xt,xu\right)}};~~~\small{\left[y=xt, z=xu\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{1-t}^{1+t}\mathrm{d}u\,x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2}S{\left(1,t,u\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{1-t}^{1+t}\mathrm{d}u\,x^{3}\sqrt{S{\left(1,t,u\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{1-t}^{1+t}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{3}\sqrt{S{\left(1,t,u\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{1-t}^{1+t}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac14\sqrt{S{\left(1,t,u\right)}}.\\
\end{align}$$

With a couple more simple substitutions, we can rewrite this double integral in a slightly less cumbersome form:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{U}
&=\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{1-t}^{1+t}\mathrm{d}u\,\sqrt{S{\left(1,t,u\right)}}\\
&=\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{1-t}^{1+t}\mathrm{d}u\,\sqrt{\frac14\sqrt{(1+t+u)(-1+t+u)(1-t+u)(1+t-u)}}\\
&=\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{1-t}^{1+t}\mathrm{d}u\,\sqrt[4]{(1+t+u)(-1+t+u)(1-t+u)(1+t-u)}\\
&=\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{1-t}^{1+t}\mathrm{d}u\,\sqrt[4]{\left[(1+t)^{2}-u^{2}\right]\left[u^{2}-(1-t)^{2}\right]}\\
&=\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{\frac{1-t}{1+t}}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,(1+t)\sqrt[4]{\left[(1+t)^{2}-(1+t)^{2}x^{2}\right]\left[(1+t)^{2}x^{2}-(1-t)^{2}\right]};~~~\small{\left[u=(1+t)x\right]}\\
&=\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{\frac{1-t}{1+t}}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,(1+t)^{2}\sqrt[4]{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left[x^{2}-\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^{2}\right]}\\
&=\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2}{(1+y)^{2}}\int_{y}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{4}{(1+y)^{2}}\sqrt[4]{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right)};~~~\small{\left[t=\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{y}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt[4]{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right)}}{\left(1+y\right)^{4}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt[4]{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right)}}{\left(1+y\right)^{4}}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

By the general binomial theorem, a binomial with negative integer exponent has the following power series expansion:

$$\left(1-z\right)^{-p}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{p+n-1}{n}z^{n};~~~\small{p\in\mathbb{N}\land|z|<1}.$$

Using the lemma above to expand the $(1+y)^{-4}$ factor of the integrand of $\mathcal{U}$ as a binomial series, we then use technique of switching the order of summation and integration to find

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{U}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,\left(1+y\right)^{-4}\sqrt[4]{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+3}{n}(-y)^{n}\sqrt[4]{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\binom{n+3}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,y^{n}\sqrt[4]{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\binom{n+3}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,x^{n+1}v^{n}\sqrt[4]{\left(1-x^{2}\right)x^{2}\left(1-v^{2}\right)};~~~\small{\left[y=xv\right]}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\binom{n+3}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,2^{-2}t^{n/2}u^{(n-1)/2}\sqrt[4]{t\left(1-t\right)\left(1-u\right)};~~~\small{\left[x^{2}=t,\,v^{2}=u\right]}\\
&=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\binom{n+3}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,t^{n/2+1/4}\left(1-t\right)^{1/4}u^{(n-1)/2}\left(1-u\right)^{1/4}\\
&=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\binom{n+3}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{n/2+1/4}\left(1-t\right)^{1/4}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,u^{(n-1)/2}\left(1-u\right)^{1/4}\\
&=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\binom{n+3}{n}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac54,\frac54\right)}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac54\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{4}\cdot\frac{(n+3)!}{n!\,3!}\cdot\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac54\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac54\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac52\right)}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac54\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac74\right)}}\\
&=\frac16\left[\Gamma{\left(\frac54\right)}\right]^{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)\,(-1)^{n}\,\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac54\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac74\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\left[\Gamma{\left(\frac54\right)}\right]^{2}}{8\,\Gamma{\left(\frac52\right)}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)\,(-1)^{n}\,\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac54\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac74\right)}}\\
&=\frac18\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac54,\frac54\right)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)\,(-1)^{n}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac54,\frac12\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where the beta function and the gamma function are defined in the usual way by their respective integral representations,

$$\operatorname{B}{\left(x,y\right)}=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{x-1}\left(1-t\right)^{y-1};~~~\small{x>0\land y>0},$$

$$\Gamma{\left(z\right)}:=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{z-1}\exp{\left(-t\right)};~~~\small{z>0},$$

and are related through the identity

$$\operatorname{B}{\left(x,y\right)}=\frac{\Gamma{\left(x\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(y\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(x+y\right)}};~~~\small{x>0\land y>0}.$$

---

Define $f$ on $(-1,1)$ by the power series

$$f{\left(z\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac54,\frac12\right)};~~~\small{|z|<1}.$$

Differentiating term-by-term, we have

$$f^{\prime}{\left(z\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nz^{n-1}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac54,\frac12\right)},$$

and it follows that

$$2f{\left(z\right)}+zf^{\prime}{\left(z\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n+2\right)z^{n}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac54,\frac12\right)}.$$

We can convert the series representation for $f$ into an integral by expressing the beta function through its integral representation and summing under the integral sign:

$$\begin{align}
f{\left(z\right)}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac54,\frac12\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{n/2+1/4}\left(1-t\right)^{-1/2}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t^{n/2+1/4}}{\sqrt{1-t}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u^{n+1}\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[t=u^{2}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2z^{n}u^{n+1}\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u\sqrt{u}}{\left(1-zu\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
f^{\prime}{\left(z\right)}
&=\frac{d}{dz}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u\sqrt{u}}{\left(1-zu\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{2u\sqrt{u}}{\left(1-zu\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u^{2}\sqrt{u}}{\left(1-zu\right)^{2}\sqrt{1-u^{2}}},\\
\end{align}$$

and so

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n+2\right)z^{n}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac54,\frac12\right)}
&=2f{\left(z\right)}+zf^{\prime}{\left(z\right)}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u\sqrt{u}}{\left(1-zu\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}+z\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u^{2}\sqrt{u}}{\left(1-zu\right)^{2}\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\left(2-zu\right)u\sqrt{u}}{\left(1-zu\right)^{2}\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}.\\
\end{align}$$

In the limit as $z\to-1^{+}$, this becomes

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n+2\right)(-1)^{n}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac54,\frac12\right)}=2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\left(2+u\right)u\sqrt{u}}{\left(1+u\right)^{2}\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}.$$

---

For any nonnegative integer $n$, observe how the following class of integrals transform:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{n}\sqrt{x\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{n}\sqrt{x\left(1-x\right)\left(1+x\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{n+1}\sqrt{x\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2}{\left(1+y\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\frac{2}{1+y}\right)^{n+1}\sqrt{y\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)}};~~~\small{\left[x=\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(1+y\right)^{n}}{2^{n}\sqrt{y\left(1-y^{2}\right)}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Also for any nonnegative integer $n$, we find

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x^{n}}{\sqrt{x\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x^{n-1/2}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t^{n/2-1/4}}{2\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}};~~~\small{\left[x=\sqrt{t}\right]}\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{n/2-3/4}\left(1-t\right)^{-1/2}\\
&=\frac12\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac14,\frac12\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

We then obtain the following result:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(2+x\right)x\sqrt{x}}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(2+x\right)x^{2}}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}\sqrt{x\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[x-\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}\right]\frac{1}{\sqrt{x\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x}{\sqrt{x\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)\sqrt{x\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}\sqrt{x\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x}{\sqrt{x\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(1+y\right)}{2\sqrt{y\left(1-y^{2}\right)}}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(1+y\right)^{2}}{2^{2}\sqrt{y\left(1-y^{2}\right)}};~~~\small{\left[x=\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x}{\sqrt{x\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}-\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{y\left(1-y^{2}\right)}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{y^{2}}{\sqrt{y\left(1-y^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\frac12\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}-\frac18\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\frac18\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac54,\frac12\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Returning finally to the evaluation of $\mathcal{U}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{U}
&=\frac18\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac54,\frac54\right)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n+2\right)(-1)^{n}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac54,\frac12\right)}\\
&=\frac14\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac54,\frac54\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(2+x\right)x\sqrt{x}}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=\frac14\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac54,\frac54\right)}\left[\frac12\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}-\frac18\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\frac18\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac54,\frac12\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{12\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\left[\Gamma{\left(\frac14\right)}\right]^{4}}{576\sqrt{2}\,\pi}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---

Now, it would be interesting if your conjectured value is *also* correct, in which case my result provides an exact value for that combination of elliptic integrals in terms of gamma functions. Perhaps that can be explored later. Cheers!

Comment: +1 for the effort!

Comment: Regarding the conjectured form it can be proved that if $n$ is a positive rational number then we have $$\frac{\pi\sqrt{n}} {4}=K(k)E(k)-A_nK^2(k)$$ where $k$ is the modulus corresponding to nome $e^{-\pi/\sqrt{n}} $ (ie $K'/K=1/\sqrt{n}$) and $A_n$ is some specific algebraic number dependent on $n$. The expression in question is for $n=5$. For $n=1$ we have $\pi/4=K(k)E(k)-(1/2)K^2(k)$ with $k=1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: So I think your final closed form is the simplest and most preferred. One can just use many well known values of $k$ and corresponding $A_n$ to generate forms like the one in question for various values of $n$.

Comment: +1 But think the complete solution involves also @ParamanandSingh answer wich explains the OP's conjecture.

Answer (score 5):

In this post we discuss the genesis of $\alpha, \phi$ present in the closed form solution given in question.

The ideas discussed below were developed by Ramanujan in his famous paper [*Modular equations and approximations to $\pi$*](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram06.html). He dealt with Dedekind eta function $$\eta(q) =q^{1/24}\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-q^n)\tag{1}$$ and its logarithmic derivative $$P(q) =24q\frac{d}{dq}\log\eta(q)=1-24\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{nq^n}{1-q^n}\tag{2}$$ If $k$ is the elliptic modulus and $K, E$ be complete elliptic integrals corresponding to nome $q$ then both the functions above can be expressed in terms of these elliptic integrals and moduli. The relations below were well known before Ramanujan's time
\begin{align} 
\eta(q^2)&=2^{-1/3}\sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi}}(kk')^{1/6}\tag{3}\\
P(q^2)&=\left(\frac{2K}{\pi}\right)^2\left(\frac{3E}{K}+k^2-2\right)\tag {4}
\end{align}
Jacobi proved in his *Fundamenta Nova* that if $r$ is a positive rational number then there is a unique algebraic number $k_r\in(0,1)$ such that $K(k'_r) /K(k_r) =\sqrt{r} $ and such values $k_r$ are called singular moduli. Many such values of singular moduli have been calculated in explicit form involving radicals for various positive integer values of $r$. Further Selberg and Chowla proved that $K(k_r) $ can be expressed in closed form involving $\pi$ and values of gamma function at rational points. In particular the values of elliptic integral $K(k_r) $ were known / given by Legendre for $r=1,2,3$.

The evaluation of $E$ occurring in $(4)$ is rather more troublesome. Ramanujan instead focused on the function $P(q^2)$ and proved that if $q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{r}} $ then the value of $P(q^2)$ could be expressed as $$P(q^2)=\frac{3}{\pi\sqrt{r}}+A_r\cdot\left(\frac{2K(k_r)}{\pi}\right)^2\tag{5}$$ where $A_r$ is some algebraic number dependent on $r$. Using this equation with $(4)$ one can get a closed form for $E(k_r) $. Comparing the equations $(4),(5)$ we get $$\frac{3}{\pi\sqrt{r}}=\left(\frac{2K(k_r)}{\pi}\right)^2\left(\frac{3E(k_r)}{K(k_r)}+k_r^2-2-A_r\right)$$ or $$\frac{\pi} {4\sqrt{r}}=K(k_r)E(k_r)+B_rK^2(k_r)\tag{6}$$ where $B_r$ is an algebraic number dependent on $r$.

Ramanujan described the process to get the values $A_r$ and gave some concrete results for small integer values of $r$. The formulas given by Ramanujan were later proved by Bruce C. Berndt and his collaborators but no new formulas of this kind have appeared for any new values of $r$.

The value of $\alpha$ given in question is a singular modulus  corresponding to nome $e^{-\pi/\sqrt{5}}$ ie $\alpha=k(e^{-\pi/\sqrt{5}})$ and this corresponds to $r=1/5$ (which is linked with $r=5$).

We have $$k_5=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt {5}-1}-\sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}}}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\phi}}-\frac{1}{\phi\sqrt{2}}$$ and $$k'_5=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt {5}-1}+\sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}}}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\phi}}+\frac{1}{\phi\sqrt{2}}=\alpha$$ Another radical needed in our calculations is $$2k_5k'_5=\sqrt{5}-2=2\phi-3$$ The value of $K(\alpha)$ is  $$K(\alpha) =\sqrt{5}K(k_5)$$ For $r=5$ Ramanujan proved that $$5P(q^{10})-P(q^2)=\frac{4KL}{\pi^2}(3+kl+k'l')\sqrt{\frac{1+kl+k'l'}{2}}$$ where moduli $k, l$ correspond to nomes $q, q^5$. Putting $q=\exp(-\pi/\sqrt{5})$ so that $k=\alpha, l=k'$ we get $$5P(e^{-2\pi\sqrt{5}})-P(e^{-2\pi/\sqrt{5}})=\frac{4KK'}{\pi^2}(3+2kk')\sqrt{\frac{1+2kk'}{2}}$$ We have $K=K(\alpha) $ and $K'=K(\alpha) /\sqrt{5}$ and $2kk'=\sqrt{5}-2$ and hence we get $$5P(e^{-2\pi\sqrt{5}})-P(e^{-2\pi/\sqrt{5}})=\frac{4K^2(\alpha)}{\pi^2}\frac{2\sqrt{\phi}}{\sqrt{5}}$$ Another identity we need here is $$rP(e^{-2\pi\sqrt{r}})+P(e^{-2\pi/\sqrt {r}})=\frac{6\sqrt{r}}{\pi}$$  Using these two equations (with $r=5$) we get $$P(q^2)=\frac{3\sqrt{5}}{\pi}-\frac{4K^2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{\phi}{\sqrt{5\phi}}$$ and comparing with $(4)$ we get $$\frac{\pi\sqrt{5}}{4}=K(\alpha)E(\alpha) - \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5\phi}}\right)K^2(\alpha)$$

Comment: (+1) Nice improvement.

Comment: Nice I don't know if you did notice that this implies: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(10n+1)(4n)!}{12^{4n}n!^4}=\frac{9\sqrt{2}}{4\pi}.$$ Which is one of Ramanujan's listed series in his famous paper.

Comment: @User: Yeah, the constant $A_r$ (or equivalently $B_r$) is related to the Ramanujan multiplier in his linked paper. Borwein brothers use the functions $\alpha (r), \sigma(r) $ for same purpose in their book "Pi and the AGM". These numbers are the key to evaluation of $E$ as well series for $1/\pi$ via Ramanujan's technique.